# Convergence of conditional probability

Tags: probability, convergence-divergence

Can anyone help me with this question:

suppose $X$ and $Y$ are non-negative random variables. Under what condition does $\lim_{\delta\rightarrow 0}\dfrac{P(Y\leq a,X\geq\delta)}{P(X\geq\delta)}=P(Y\leq a)$? I think a sufficient condition is $P(X=0)=0$, but is it necessary?

In addition, if $X$ and $Y$ are related in the following sense:

suppose $Z$ is a non-negative random variable. $X=f(Z)$ and $Y=g(Z)$, where $f$ and $g$ are non-decreasing, non-negative functions. Will the solution change?

Answer (score 0):

Using the Bayes rule,

$$\lim_{\delta\downarrow 0} P(Y\leq a,X\geq\delta)=\lim_{\delta\downarrow 0}P(Y\leq a|X\geq\delta)P(X\geq\delta)=\lim_{\delta\downarrow 0}P(Y\leq a|X\geq\delta)=P(Y\leq a)$$

which is true for every random variable $X$ and $Y$, if $X$ has no degenerate distributions at $X=0$.

If $X$ has a degenerate distribution at $X=0$, then, in general, $\lim_{\delta\downarrow 0}P(Y\leq a|X\geq\delta)\neq P(Y\leq a)$.

However, if $X$ and $Y$ are independent, then, $$ P(Y\leq a,X\geq\delta)=P(X\geq\delta)P(Y\leq a).$$
for every $\delta$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. In my original post, I have used Bayes rule to convert $P(Y\leq a|X\geq \delta)$ to $P(Y\leq a, X\geq \delta)/P(X\geq \delta)$, so that convergence theorems can be conveniently used (since probabilities are expectations of indicator functions). Is there any theorem directly addressing conditional probability, or is there any result on necessity of the degeneration (it is clearly sufficient)? Thanks.